# Background shading for a group of styles, or for everything under a heading

Tags: microsoft-word

I would like certain sections of my document to have a light grey backgroud. These sections contain several styles, for example: Heading, text, bulleted list.

Is there a way to define this for a given group of styles, or to define a style that affects everything under it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom styles for Heading, text, bulleted list respectively. For example, select the Heading in the document, apply a **shading** for it. Then select it, click **Create a style**, you can create a heading style based on your current setting.

After creating the styles, you can apply the style manually for different parts in the document. Additionally, you can save the document as a personal template for further using.